# Zip and Download

Tags: php

I use this code to zip and download files with PHP
Browser start ZIP download, but is corrupt.
When i try to open browser say's Format file unknown or damaged.

Any tip to solve?

```
$files = array('1.png', '2.png');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
obclean();
flush();
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Not sure it's related, but you're using `$zipfilename` in the `filesize()` call, but that's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure the zip is created?

Comment: What is the output if you delete lines containing `header(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed this line to work:

FROM:

```
$zip->addFile($file);
```

TO:

```
$zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
obclean();
```

Change it to:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
ob_clean();
```